# Why am I getting unreported Exception?

Tags: java, exception

Why am I getting the error message "unreported exception StupidNameException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"?

Here are my code blocks:

```
/**
 * @throws StupidNameException
 */
abstract class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) throws StupidNameException {
        if (firstName == "Jason") {
           throw new StupidNameException("first name cannot be null");
        } 
        this.firstName = firstName;

        if (lastName == "Harrisson") {
            throw new StupidNameException("last name cannot be null");
        }
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // Rest of class goes here ...
}

class Student  extends Person {
    private String ultimateGoal;
    private double GPA;

    /**
     * @throws StupidNameException when name is "Jason" or "Harrisson"
     */
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String ultimateGoal, double GPA) {
        super(firstName, lastName);
        this.ultimateGoal = ultimateGoal;
        this.GPA = GPA;
    }

    // Rest of class goes here ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Fix the formatting and show us the stacktrace you get.

Comment: Also clean the code to minimal test case. I won't read irrelevant code.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like you're writing a program to make fun of someone named Jason Harrisson...

Comment: Fun as a motivation to start programming... why not

Answer (score 5):

Look at the documentation you wrote yourself:

```
/**
 * @throws StupidNameException when name is "Jason" or "Harrisson"
 */
public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String ultimateGoal, double GPA) {
    // ...
```

Where's the `throws StupidNameException`? The Java compiler is wondering about that.

Fix it accordingly:

```
/**
 * @throws StupidNameException when name is "Jason" or "Harrisson"
 */
public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String ultimateGoal, double GPA) throws StupidNameException {
    // ...
```

This is necessary, because you're calling a `super(firstName,lastName)` which by itself throws that exception. It has either to be caught in a `try-catch`, or, better, to be passed through by `throws`.

Comment: Can you be more concrete? Sorry, I'm not really following.

Comment: You forgot the `throws StupidNameException` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using "==" to compare Strings. You need to use [equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) or [equalsIgnoreCase()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) (if case does not matter) to compare string objects. Change the following lines of code to what I have:-

```
    if(firstName!=null && firstName.equals("Jason")) {
        throw new StupidNameException("first name cannot be null");
    } 

        this.firstName = firstName;

    if(lastName!=null && lastName.equals("Harrisson")) {
        throw new StupidNameException("last name cannot be null");
    }
```

Although I am not sure why you want throw Null exception when the name is "Jason" or "Harrison". They are clearly not null.

It is a better practice to throw [IllegalArgumentException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) for arguments that you expect to be not null instead of your custom exception like you are doing now.

Since you updated your post with a proper question, as @BalusC mentioned your problem lies in not defining your exception class. However, you still need to fix what I mentioned in my answer as well.

Comment: That's indeed a major mistake, but not the answer to OP's concrete question :)

Comment: @BalusC - when I answered the first sentence of the post was not there. I thought he meant his code was not throwing StupidNameException as he intended. Now after his post updates, you are correct this is a major issue but not the exact question.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway. Some method you call in your code throws StupidNameException. You must handle it in `try { ... } catch () ...` or add `throws StupidNameException` to the method where you call it.

In your case, the "method" is the constructor of `Student`.
Because the constructor of super class throws `Stupid...`, subclass'es constructor must also throw, or you must do `try { super( ... ) } catch( ... ) { ... }`.

Comment: Can you be more concrete? I tried adding throws StupidNameException to the constructor, now I'm getting "Illegal start of expression"